# C#: Anonymous types and property names

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

Is there any difference at all between this:

```
dataContext.People.Select(ø => new
{
     Name = ø.Name,
});
```

and this:

```
dataContext.People.Select(ø => new
{
     ø.Name,
});
```

?

Comment: What is this ->'ø'? Phi?

Comment: It's a norwegian character. æ, ø and å. I usually use ø for lambda stuff, since no other things in .Net or the code starts with that letter. Which means the intellisense wont kick in :) Also I actually think that letter makes the lambda look better :p

Comment: Lol, you could have used λ. But I like the scandinavian touch ;-).

Comment: λ does not have easy access on my keyboard :p ø is next to my L key, so it is very easy to get to with my pinky ;)

Comment: And just after I hit "Add Comment" I got your point with using λ since that is Lambda... *doh*, haha. But the access thing still counts :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are identical; if no name is specified (and the right-hand-side is a simple member-access) then the name of the existing member is assumed. The name is only necessary to:

- change the name to something *else* (for example `Name = grp.Key`)
- to give a name to a non-member-access expression (for example `Count = grp.Count()`)

Comment: on his reputation, it looks like he has some practice :p

Answer (score 1):

No.  The second simply derives the name of the property for you, the actual code generated is the same.

Answer (score 1):

No, the compiler will name the property of the anonymous type the same as the right hand side of the assignment.