# Example of OrmLite UpdateOnly with Multiple Fields

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Is it possible to use the OrmLite extension method **UpdateOnly** to update multiple fields at once?

The example given in the documentation is:

```
db.UpdateOnly(new Person { FirstName = "JJ" }, p => p.FirstName);
```

Can I provide an expression with multiple fields in it? If so, what's the best operator to use given that the fields may be different data types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An example was give in the following question:
[ServiceStack Ormlite and RowVersion support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761830/servicestack-ormlite-and-rowversion-support)

A valid expression to use is an anonymous type; even one with implicit member names as described in this question: [C#: Anonymous types and property names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545270/c-anonymous-types-and-property-names).

```
db.UpdateOnly(new Person { FirstName = "JJ", Age = 12 }, 
    (Person p) => new { p.FirstName, p.Age } );
```

Note that in my example I declared the type of the lambda argument. This may not be strictly necessary, but I was getting a Mono compiler error without it.

```
Error CS0016: Could not write to file `***', cause: Type '<>__AnonType1`2' was not completed.
```